# How can journey data be used in a Journey Builder Wait Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, wait-element

I have a Customer who has signed up for an event and want to send an Email 2 days before the event happens.   The event data is in the Journey Data.  However when I come to make a Wait Activity, I can only choose attributes from Contact Data.  Since there's a 1:N relationship between Contact and Event Attendance I can't use the Event date from that relationship.   If there are multiple events it will chose the wrong one.

How do I access the attributes from the Data Extension that starts the Journey from a Wait Activity?

Comment: Attribute to Attribute comparison may help here. See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_data_relationships.htm&type=5

Comment: You should be able to use a date from journey data in a wait step, is the field a date field type?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this, in the end it appeared the DE selected for entry has been corrupted somehow - the name was corrupted on Journey Builder itself.  This for some reason caused Journey attributes to be available in Decision Splits but not Wait Activities.

Re-saving the overall journey and ensuring the DE appeared correctly fixed this.   Journey attributes available in Wait Activity again..

Thanks